# How to import files while running?

Tags: python, import

I have following Problem:

`file1.py` has functions and variables wich I need for `file2.py`.
With `from file1 import myclass1` there is no problem with that.
The problem is, I also want to "send" variables from `file2.py` to `file1.py` while running `file2.py`

`from file1 import myclass1` in `file2.py` doesnt work because when i compile `file2.py` it apears an ImportError:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "****\file1.py", line 13, in <module>
      from file1 import myclass1
   File "****\forfile1.py", line 7, in <module>
      from file2 import myclass2
   File "****\file1.py", line 13, in <module>
      from file1 import myclass1
ImportError: cannot import name s4dat_class
```

So, how can u import files, while running? or are there other ways to do what I want? Thx

Comment: What do you mean by "send" variables?  It's usually a bad sign if you have two modules that are importing each other.  Please explain what your modules are doing that requires them to access one another.

Comment: i think you meant share a variable between two executed scripts ?

Comment: First I had only one little programm (file2.py). Then i made a programm with more functions (file1.py). One of these functions is to work with the output from the first little programm. Problem is that the input for file2.py comes from file1.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "how do I import from module1 into module2 when module2 imports from module1", the simple answer is "you can't", and the solution is either

- merge both modules,
- or extract the common dependencies into a third module
- or pass needed objects (hint : classes and functions are objects too) as function or method params (simplest form of dependency injection).

The complete answer is that there are workarounds (like importing from within a function body), but that's fugly and 99.8% of the time (approximately ) a sure design smell - you *should* not have cyclic dependencies so better to cure the design than resort to fugly workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

in file_2.py you can type:

```
my_module = __import__("file_1")  # assuming file_1.py in the python path.
```

then you can use `my_module` as it was `file_1`

But in order to achive what you want I recommend you put all those things that are common to `file_1.py` and `file2_py` in a separated file `file_3.py` for instance. Then you can import `file_3.py` in both.